# Firebase gives me error 'unsupported browser'

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire

I try to get notifications with firebase, I'm using angular 6 and @angular/fire module for firebase. I have done all setups for it, but it does't work, gives me "Messaging: This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the firebase SDK. (messaging/unsupported-browser)."I test it in google chrome Version 72.0.3626.81.

I have done all from medium tutorial '"Push Notifications with Angular 6 + Firebase Cloud Messaging". And also I added vapId, in tutorial about it nothing and I don't know why is it.

I create messaging service, this is in constructor.

```
this.angularFireMessaging.messaging.subscribe(
  (_messaging) => {
    _messaging.onMessage = _messaging.onMessage.bind(_messaging);
    _messaging.onTokenRefresh = 
     _messaging.onTokenRefresh.bind(_messaging);
    _messaging.usePublicVapidKey("BKulE7o.......m2IsHicRWn8");

  }
)
```

this is function for getting permission.

```
requestPermission() {
this.angularFireMessaging.requestToken.subscribe(
  (token) => {
    console.log(token);
  },
  (err) => {
    console.error('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
  }
);
```

}

this is in app.module.ts

```
 AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
```

AngularFireMessagingModule,

And I call this functions in app.component.ts

```
this.messagingService.requestPermission()
```

this.messagingService.receiveMessage()

I want to get notification from the server, I want to get token and send it to server.

Answer (score 0):

Is your site running on HTTPS ? The Firebase Cloud Messaging uses Service Woker, which would only works on HTTPS

Comment: I run it with heroku cli.

Comment: I would look up how to issue SSL Certificate on Heroku. In the meantime, you can use Firebase Hosting to test, I know they issue SSL certificate automatically

Comment: Okay I will try